# How React schedules function execution inside an event handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple function as below. I understand `setState` run as an async function, therefore the result should like:
1
3
2.1
2.2
............
But in the first Click, the result is:
1
2.1
3
2.2
..............
Means that the first `setCount` executed in a sync way, and for all the next Clicks, the code run normally (
1
3
2.1
2.2
............). Can I ask why this behavior happens?  Thanks.

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('1');

    setCount((prevCount) => {
      console.log('2.1');
      return prevCount + 1;
    });

    setCount((prevCount) => {
      console.log('2.2');
      console.log('------------');
      return prevCount + 1;
    });

    console.log('3');
```

Comment: While this is a good question, it's worth pointing out that asynchronous code can coincidentally execute in the same order as synchronous code would have (though if this is reproducible every time, that's likely not the case here)

Comment: Why? Because React scheduled it that way. Afaik you have no guarantees from React when your `setCount`  callback will be executed, except that it will happen in the same order as you called them. (why) do you rely on the order in which this happens?

Comment: React state update functions, i.e. `setState`, are 100% *synchronous* functions, they are not `async` at all as they are not declared `async` nor do they return a Promise to `await` on. The state updater functions, i.e. the callbacks, can be called anytime React needs to, only the order of updates is maintained. Is there any actual issue in any real code you are trying to use?

Comment: @DrewReese `setState` is asynchronous inside event handlers. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous

Comment: @nghiepit The `setState` function itself is still a ***synchronous*** function. What that link is describing is *how* enqueued updates are processed, not the function itself that is used to enqueue the update. In Javascript, "asynchronous" code is not the same as `async` functions. The asynchronous part is referring to the fact that React defers the update and you can't count on it occurring by the next line of code. `setState` is a synchronous function no matter where it is called.